# onchange event using jquery is not working in IE

Tags: jquery

i'm not able to use "onchange" of jquery event in IE, but its working in firefox and chrome.

my code

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('change',function() {
```

This should work on a textbox only when I enter the textbox

Comment: Please provide the version of Internet Explorer you are using.

Comment: If you are using a jQuery 2.x version, IE 9+ is supported only.

Comment: I'm testing in IE 11

Answer (score 1):

Actually Onchange does not work very well in IE. Here is what I did while using Javascript. You can replicate it accordingly.

1. Add ondrop event in HTML to call the function being called now, instead of onchange.
2. Add the following code in your js file

   ```
   document.getElementById('--your selector--').ondragover = handle;

   function handle(evt)
   {
       evt.stopPropagation();
       evt.preventDefault();
       evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
   }
   ```
3. The ondragover will be made false by above code, and then ondrop will fire on all browsers and call the required function

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="newstaggered-carousel">
    <input type="text" name="otherCityInputField">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('change',function() { 
    console.log('changed');
});
```

This should work in IE